# pandas pivot dataframe with multiple groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with data like this:

df:

```
     item   day         time      data  
0   item_0  2012-12-02  00:00:01  0.81  
1   item_0  2012-12-02  00:00:02  0.07
2   item_0  2012-12-03  00:00:00  0.84  
3   item_1  2012-12-02  00:00:01  0.47
```

The combination of item+day+time are unique

I am trying to transform to:

```
     item   day         time_0    time_1   time_2  
0   item_0  2012-12-02  NaN       0.81     0.07
1   item_0  2012-12-03  0.84      NaN      NaN  
2   item_1  2012-12-02  NaN       0.47     ...
```

I have tried:

```
df_stage_1 = df.groupby(['item','day']).apply(lambda x: x['time'].tolist()).reset_index()
```

the code above produces a list but times are not aligned from 00:00:00 - I could just check the list and add and track the indexes (so can add Nan to value list at these indexes)

```
df_stage_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_stage_1.tolist(), )
```

the code above gives me a dataframe of (unaligned) time values, which I could align (see above) and append to dataframe created in step above, but I cant work out how to get values for dataframe in correct time aligned columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index=['item', 'day'], columns='time',
                     values='data', aggfunc='first').reset_index()

print(res)

time    item         day  00:00:00  00:00:01  00:00:02
0     item_0  2012-12-02       NaN      0.81      0.07
1     item_0  2012-12-03      0.84       NaN       NaN
2     item_1  2012-12-02       NaN      0.47       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is `set_index`, `unstack`, `reset_index`:

```
df.set_index(['item', 'day', 'time'])['data'].unstack().reset_index()

time    item         day  00:00:00  00:00:01  00:00:02
0     item_0  2012-12-02       NaN      0.81      0.07
1     item_0  2012-12-03      0.84       NaN       NaN
2     item_1  2012-12-02       NaN      0.47       NaN
```

Remember that `df.unstack` in pandas refers to the index: it *unstacks* the innermost level of the index and pivots it into the columns.